# To prove a matrix is PSD

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

This question rises from the proof of the outer product Cholesky Factorization.

If the matrix
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha&\vec{q}^T \\
\vec{q}&N
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is positive semidefinite with $\alpha>0$, then the matrix
$$
A := N-\frac{1}{\alpha} \vec{q}\vec{q}^T
$$
is also positive semidefinite.

I have proved that the matrix $A$ is symmetric, which is easy, but I don’t know how to prove it is PSD. Any hints?

Comment: Take a look at the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semi-definiteness).

Comment: Indeed, a Schur's complement of a PSD is itself PSD.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks! Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $M$ is PSD, hence
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}^TM\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=
\alpha x^2+2x\cdot q^Ty+y^TNy\ge 0,\qquad\forall x,y\tag{*}
$$
Complete the squares in (*)
$$
\alpha\left(x+\frac{1}{\alpha}q^Ty\right)^2+y^T\left(N-\frac{1}{\alpha}qq^T\right)y\ge 0,\qquad\forall x,y.
$$
Take $x=-\frac{1}{\alpha}q^Ty$ to get
$$
y^T\left(N-\frac{1}{\alpha}qq^T\right)y\ge 0,\qquad\forall y.
$$